# Adding my first view to a window based application

Tags: iphone

I'm beginner with iPhone and want to know how to add a view in a window based application.

I crate the application, then I added the ViewControler+XIB to my project.
I include the .h file in both AppDelegate-Files.

Then I create a object of the View "StartViewController" with

```
StartViewController *startView;
```

and add the property in the AppDelegate.h file:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) StartViewController *startView;
```

In the AppDelegate.m I add:

```
@synthessize startViewController
```

and in the application method:

```
[window addSubview:startViewController.view];
```

But it doesn't appear when I start the application, what I forgot?

Comment: have you connected the UIView with Interface builder? ? ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not allocating or initializing it anywhere that I can see. From what you're saying, it seems like you need to put in a

```
startView = [[StartViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"xib filename without dot xib" bundle:nil];
```

If this doesn't sound right, it may instead be that you aren't setting Interface Builder up right. How is the main window linking to this XIB / view controller of yours? Do you have it referenced as a view?

Answer (score 1):

I'm beginner with iPhone and want to know how to add a view in a window based application

STEP 1:
Open Xcode Create New Project Select Window Based Application.Name is Some x
that is display two files xappdeligate.h and xappdelegate.m.

Step 2:
in project click right button add ui view controller name is FirstViewController  that is displays FirstViewController .h , FirstViewController .m

Step 3:
In xappdeligate.h we have to write

```
   FirstViewController *viewController;
```

define Property:

```
@property(nonatomic,retain)FirstViewController *viewController;
```

Step: 4

In xappdelegate.m we have to synthesize to them

```
@synthesize viewController;
```

allocate thememory:

```
   viewController = [[FirstViewController alloc]init];
```

add view to the window:

```
[self.window addSubview:FirstViewController.view];
```

Step: 5

We should compulsary release the memory for this in

```
-(void)dealloc
{
[window release];
[viewController release];

}
```

this is simple way to add view to the window.

Ur's Raffi 37...

Answer (score 0):

Just connect the view with interface builder by dragging.

and still if you can't connect , [here](http://appsamuck.com/) is link where a number of applications are provided to learn iPhone applications.